# Difference between XMSS and MSS-SPR

Tags: signature, hash-signature

I am currently studying stateful hash based signatures. In the [XMSS paper](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?cluster=1040077284760329271&hl=fr&as_sdt=0,5) the authors claim that XMSS signatures are 4 times smaller than those of [MSS-SPR](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?cluster=7973556097502861580&hl=fr&as_sdt=0,5). However I do not get how it is possible,
because I do not understand the differences between both of them.

As the paper of MSS-SPR does not contain any One Time Signature scheme, a fair comparison should use the same OTS in both schemes. The only other difference I get is pseudo-random versus true random but it is unsufficient because it should not affect signature size:

- pseudo-random generation of secret keys must not change the signature at all
- pseudo-random generation of salt is helpful to reduce the public key size, but should not change the signature size either

So can someone explain to me where does this factor 4 come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As the paper of MSS-SPR does not contain any One Time Signature scheme

Actually, that's not true; they assume Lamport signatures (specifically, a version they call LD-OTS).

```
When using the LD–OTS, the one-time signature of the message consists of
n bit strings of length n. The veriﬁcation key also consists of n bit
strings of length n, since half of the veriﬁcation key can be computed
from the signature.
```

Hence, the OTS signature is $2n^2$ bits long; in contrast, a WOTS+ signature (which XMSS uses) is $(n/4+3)n$ bits long, considerably shorter.

Now, the difference is actually larger than a factor of 4 - I believe that, if we take account of the fixed overhead of the authentication path (which is the same in both cases), and MSS-SPR's use of a somewhat smaller $n$, the two are closer.

> a fair comparison should use the same OTS in both schemes.

True; however as specified, the comparison isn't fair.

As for why MSS-SPR uses LD-OTS (rather than some Winternitz-based scheme), I'm not one of the designers, and so I can't be certain.  My best guess is that they couldn't come up with a shorter scheme that preserves the "not relying on collision resistance" property (which WOTS+ does).

Comment: I missed that claim. For the "why" question, the WOTS paper used in XMSS has been published later than the MSS-SPR, so it is quite clear. It's quite sad such an unfair comparison has been published without modification.